# Capture RAW (non decoded) $_GET data in PHP

Tags: php, get, capture

I am running some tests to understand subtle nuances between various browsers / OSs and how they send data via different methods, ajax, stand posts & get, jQuery, etc. so I need to capture data as it comes through to the server, unaltered.

I have a PHP script that is capturing RAW POST data using php://input, but I'm unclear on how to achieve a similar stream for data sent via GET.   The $_GET array url decodes my data, which for this sets of tests I do not want.  I want the RAW URL encoded data as sent to in the GET request.

Is there a quick way to do this in PHP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` value and parse that.

Comment: You may also be interested in the documentation found here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php.  The` $_SERVER` superglobal is full of request information which may be relevant to you.